# Select2 неправильно работает при прокрутке в модалке

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, select2

Столкнулись с проблемой, что Select2 неправильно работает, когда при появлении бутстраповской модалки прокручиваем вниз.

В описанной ситуации, select2 раскрывает список вариантов, перекрывая само поле, из-за чего выбирается первый повашийся под курсор элемент.

Пробовал менять `dropdownParent` на body, .modal, .modal.in, форму модалки, но ситуация повторяется.

Из особеннойстей модалки - перед ее открытием отправляется ajax дял получения формы и данных для нее, после данные загружаются в блок контента модалки через `.html(data);` и только потом ставятся обработчики, в тч select2

Возможно это связано с тем, что модалка больше высоты окна. После проявления этой "фичи" ее можно убрать, прокрутив модалку вверх/вниз, но это плохо для пользователей

Сделать блок в модалке overflow-y тое нельзя.

Есть варианты решения?

---

Версия: `4.0.3` . Пробовал `4.0.10` - эффект тот же

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, смена позиции дропдауна при `select:open` не давало эффекта и я решил попробовать менять не его позицию, а дочернего элемента. Через JS добавил ему позицию absolute и расчитанное смещение относительно родителя и ему поставил новое значение `top`